# Disable text cursor in custom terminal in C

Tags: c, kernel, osdev

this might already be answered somewhere, so would appreciate a link if so.

I have successfully enabled a blinking cursor on my OS terminal (linux-based) using the following method:

```
#define FB_CMD_PORT             0x3D4
#define FB_DATA_PORT            0x3D5

#define FB_HIGH_BYTE_CMD        14
#define FB_LOW_BYTE_CMD         15

void enable_cursor( uint8_t cursor_start, uint8_t cursor_end ) {
    write_port( FB_CMD_PORT, 0x0A );
    write_port( FB_DATA_PORT, (read_port(FB_DATA_PORT) & 0xC0) | cursor_start );

    write_port( FB_CMD_PORT, 0x0B );
    write_port( FB_DATA_PORT, (read_port(FB_DATA_PORT) & 0xE0) | cursor_end );
}
```

Could anyone tell me how to do the inverse of this? I.e. disable the cursor. After the user has typed the thing they need to type, I want the cursor to vanish. I'm sure it's simple, but my brain is fried right now.

Thank you

Comment: maybe this could help: https://wiki.osdev.org/Text_Mode_Cursor

Comment: That was exactly what I needed to see. Thank you :)